# Finding an Abelian subgroup S5 of order 6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let me just first clarify what I am looking for here.  I am looking for a permutation $\sigma$ with five elements and its product will generate a permutation with 6 elements?  I'm not so sure how that is possible.  I mean even if they were disjoint one would just take the lcm of the two which will still not amount to 6.  How would you approach this and what theorem/concepts might you use?

Comment: Can you get $6$ as the lcm of two smaller numbers? Two such that their sum is $\le5$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the element: $(1 2 3)(45)$. Show that this element has order $6$

Comment: Do you just take the lcm (2,3) which is 6 since these are two disjoint cycles, yet when you multiply them through to get a permutation matrix it is in $S_5$?

Comment: Yes- that's right